# How I can query for specific data using angularjs,nodejs and mongodb?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to nodejs and angularjs and hope I can get some help here.
I am trying to create a small application for learning .I am using angularjs,Mongodb and nodejs.
How I can query for a problem based on a specific idea id passed as a parameter using the following given??
I have the following :I created the problem service and an idea service:

```
app.factory('Problem', 
          ['$rootScope', '$resource',
  function ($rootScope,   $resource) {

    return $resource($rootScope.apiBaseURL + '/problems/:id', {id:'@id'}, {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    });
}]);
```

I have also the problem controller:

```
app.controller('ProblemController', [
           '$rootScope','$scope', 'Problem',
  function ($rootScope,$scope, Problem) {
    //$scope.htmlVariable = 'Explain why you selected this problem… What is the need that you are trying to fulfill?(Please make sure to limit your answer to 140 Words)';
     $scope.problem = Problem.query();
  }]
```

Back-end:

```
use strict';

// modules dependencies
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Problem     = mongoose.model('Problem');

/**
 * create problem
 */
exports.create = function (req, res) {
  var newProblem = new Problem(req.body);

  newProblem.save(function(err) {
    if (err) return res.status(400).send(err)

    res.json(newProblem);
  });
};

/**
 * update problem
 */
exports.update = function (req, res) {
  //TODO check token
};


/**
 *  get problem by id
 */
exports.getById = function (req, res) {

  Problem.findById(req.params.id, function (err, problem) {
    if (err) return res.status(400).send(err)

    if (problem) {
      res.send(problem);
    } else {
      res.status(404).send('Problem not found')
    }
  });
};

/**
 *  get all problems
 */
exports.getAll = function (req, res) {

  Problem.find(function (err, problems) {
    if (err) return res.status(400).send(err)

    res.send(problems);
  });
};
    );
```

Problem schema:

```
'use strict';

// modules dependencies
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

// model
var ProblemSchema = new Schema({

  description: {
    type     : String,
    unique   : false,
    required : false
  },
  creator: {
    type     : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    unique   : false,
    required : true,
    ref      : 'User'
  },
  idea: {
    type     : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    unique   : false,
    required : true,
    ref      : 'Idea'
  }
});

mongoose.model('Problem', ProblemSchema);
```

Routes:

```
// problem routes
  var problemController = require('../controllers/problemController');
  router.post   ('/problems',     authController.isBearerAuthenticated, problemController.create );
  router.put    ('/problems/:id', authController.isBearerAuthenticated, problemController.update );
  router.get    ('/problems/:id', authController.isBearerAuthenticated, problemController.getById);
  router.get    ('/problems',     authController.isBearerAuthenticated, problemController.getAll );
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to make async call which data will be available after some time..you need to get its data inside `$resource` promise like below

```
Problem.query({id: 2}).$promise
.then(function(data){ 
    $scope.problem = data; 
});
```

Comment: How do I query for a specific problem based on the idea id ??

Comment: Problem.query() is working fine and it is retrieving all problems in the problem schema

Comment: How I can inject idea id so that exports.getById = function (req, res) will query for problem based on the idea id not problem id ??I have 2 schemas in Mongodb one for problem and another for Idea.

Comment: @Abadi it seems like you handled that on server side.. honestly saying I didn't work on MEAN.